# Removing text from textarea with jquery ajax call not working

Tags: jquery

I have this code that works, but only if the button is clicked for the first time:

```
<script> 

$(document).on("click","#btn-regenerate", function () {

        var something = "blablabla";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url_admin + "sitemap/getcategories",
            data: {"something" : something},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg){
              $("#categories").html(msg);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
              alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
});

</script>
```

But after the first time it is not working. Why? I want on click to remove the previous content in the textarea and put the ajax output there again (no matter how many times I click the button). But it works only for the first time. Then when I e.g. delete manually some of the content in textarea and click on the button, nothing happens. How to fix that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you also show the HTML?

Comment: Please provide us a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#categories").html(msg);
```

try with:

```
$("#categories").val(msg);
```

Comment: Wow, it works ;D. Could you please explain why html() can be used only once and val() multiple times?

Comment: `.html()` sets directly HTML code in given element, so it works for empty `textarea`. After that `textarea` inherits it as a value and it covers HTML code. Also if you set value in it manually, it does not modify its HTML code (still just value).

Answer (score 0):

I think `#btn-regenerate` is inserted after calling ajax , so you must bind click event on it after calling ajax

Answer (score 0):

first remove the html content of $("#categories") as

```
 $("#categories").html('');
```

before the ajax call and then apppend the html content in the response

```
$("#categories").html(msg);
```